# Android(java), laptop(c++) udp capacity

Tags: android, c++, udp

I am quite aware that udp is not a reliable protocol.

But I see some difference in reliability when I test it with an android device and a laptop.

For example, I have a device that sends udp packets and I am doing a receiving test with a laptop and Android. When testing it with a laptop(a simple udp receiver written in c++), there are merely no losses. Almost no loss occurs.

But when I test it with an android smartphone, the loss rate dramatically increases. About 10% of packet loss occurs.

Why am I resulting in such difference? Is this just a difference of capacity caused by hardware spec?